# dom element creation with jquery causes ie9 to give access denied error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to inject an element into the DOM via

```
$('<div class=\"slideshow\"></div>')
```

which works fine except in IE9, which says

```
SCRIPT5: Access denied
```

but I am not doing a cross domain http request. I tried isolating that single line of code in the console, so I know this is the origin of the error.

Any advice on what may be going on?

Comment: escaping the double quotes is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**createElement**()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) javascript method.

```
div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.className = "slideshow";
```